# Multi monitor thoroughput - getting my head around the numbers

Tags: usb, display, thunderbolt

I want to link 12 Display Port (eDP) panels with 2048x1536 resolution each.

The problem I have is with the hardware that will(theoretically at least) be needed to drive all this.

I was told that an Intel NUC i5 5th generation has a "bad chipset" with USB 3.0 limiting possible multi monitor throughput.

Looking forward and into the future NUC like devices...

Thunderbolt 3 with 40GB/s and a Z170 chipset , Alpine ridge chipset or whatever the latest high throughput chipset is.... What options do I have ? I have seen a PCI 3 to USB 3.1 card...perhaps a Pcie 3(or pcie 4) to thunderbolt 3 can somehow max out all hardware throughput?

Does the pcie 3 (or pcie 4) card affect the bandwidth to a built in thunderbolt 3 port?

P.S. I know thunderbolt 3 has just been announced and USB 3.1 is also something new ...is a multiple USB 3.1 port system capable to carry the 12 monitors at 2048x1536??

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this to Superuser.SE since it's not about electronic design.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing some raw calculations:

12 displays at 60Hz with a resolution of 2048x1536 takes requires 6.33GB/s of uncompressed bandwidth (assuming 24-bit RGB). This is much faster than USB 3.0's raw limit of 5 G**bits**/s (or 625 MB/s), even before taking USB 3.0's protocol overhead into account.

Thunderbolt 3.0 is specified to have 40G**bits**/S, which is only 5GB/s, still not fast enough before taking into account Thunderbolt's protocol overhead.

Bottom line, no. You're not going to be able to drive 12 monitors using a single display daisy chain. [A single modern discrete graphics card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Eyefinity) can support up to 6 monitors at that resolution in theory, though I doubt you'd get good performance even then with software running on all the displays. At a company I used to work for that required a large number of high resolution displays they used a server rack with a high-end GPU in each node to handle all the displays and software.

Comment: anyhow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMbHZ8Mn__g